# Remotely Loading Images in an iPhone App

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7, uiimageview

An app that I am making will contain mass amounts of images. So obviously it would be really bad to store them all on the users phone and take up all the disk space. As I am new to iOS Development, how would I best go about loading an image remotely into a UIImageView. What are my options?

Just to let you know I would only ever be loading a maximum of 2 images at a time, if it helps.

Any advise would be very much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You want to load images from server?

Comment: Store them online and load a UIImage from a url.

Comment: I would preferably like to store them somewhere online for free or a low price and load them. I don't want to be running it from a personal server.

Comment: @CW0007007 Where would be best to store them? Which provider? Would I need to include credentials in my code to pull the image?

Comment: If you have a images on server then use SDWEBIMAGE.

Comment: Parse offer a good backend service where you could store the images. Essentially all you need is a URL so you *could* just store them on dropbox and copy the urls ... Parse would be better as you can add images and remove images without modifying your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can download image Asynchronously by unblocking the main thread using the below code

```
NSURLRequest* request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"Your imageURL"]];
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc]init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
         {
             if (error==nil && [data length]>0)
             {
              UIImage* img=[UIImage imageWithData:data];
              // set the downloaded image to imageview here 
              }
             else
             {
                 NSLog(@"%@",error);

             }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [SDImageView](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) or similar open sources, another options if you are loading images in table, use [Lazy Loading by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: Thank you, I will give these a try. What provider is best to host my images from? Will any provider do, or does it have to be a specific type of provider? e.g. Dropbox etc